# Convergence of $\sum_{t=1}^\infty r\frac{1}{(1+r)^t}\cdot t$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Please show convergence of this sum for $r>0$:

$$D=r\sum_{t=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1+r)^t}\cdot t\rightarrow \frac{1}{r}$$

Comment: Hint: divide by $(1+r)$ and add the sum without the $\cdot t$ factor (which is a geometric series). Relate to the original sum.

Comment: No, I said divide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$S_m=\sum_{k=1}^mkx^k=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(k+1)x^{k+1}=x+x\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}kx^k+x\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}x^k.$$

Then,

$$(1-x)S_m=x\frac {1-x^m}{1-x}.$$

As $x=\dfrac1{1+r}<1$, the sum converges.

Comment: I tried to apply your formula: $$\Rightarrow S_m=\frac {x}{(1-x)^2}=\frac {\dfrac1{1+r}}{(1-\dfrac1{1+r})^2}$$

$$\Rightarrow D=\frac {\dfrac{r}{1+r}}{(1-\dfrac1{1+r})^2}$$
However, I was unable to show the desired result $D=\frac{1}{r}$.

Comment: That's because the claimed formula is wrong. Take $r$ very large and the first term is about $1$, and so is $D$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you differentiate the standard formula [geometric power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n \;=\; \frac{1}{1-x}$$
you'll get
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x^{n-1} \;=\; \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
and this is directly applicable to you question. Don't forget to check the convergence criteria for geometric power series.

Comment: I applied your argument, but it doesnt seem to add up to $r$ (as I was expecting it should): $\frac{r}{1+r}\sum_{t=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^{t-1}\cdot t\rightarrow\frac{r}{(1+r)(1-\frac{1}{1+r})^2}$

Comment: Shouldnt the derived sum also start at $n=0$?

Comment: @emcor The term for $n=0$ is $x^0=1$, so after differentiation it'll be equal to $0$. Note that in your case the form of the sum is $\sum n x^n$, while after the differentiation the formula is $\sum n x^{n-1}$.  But if you multiply the inner terms by $x$, you'll get $\frac{1}{x}\sum n x^n$.

Comment: I dont see what you mean, please write out the derivation in your answer.

Comment: @emcor As this seems to be an exercise, I don't want to disclose the full solutions, just give hints how to get there - this is much better for learning.